# Guidance on organizing routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I am working on this project that has products and under products I have cars and trucks and each have comments and the ability to vote on both the car model and comments. The car models all work correctly but the trucks model does not have the correct routes. I am thinking it has something to do with having comments shallow, but honestly, I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any guidance would be appreciated.

```
  resources :products do 
  resources :cars  do 
    member { post :vote }
  resources :car_comments, shallow: true do
    member { post :vote }
      end
    end
  resources :trucks do 
    member { post :vote }
  resources :truck_comments, shallow: true do
    member { post :vote }

    end
  end
end
```

**UPDATE**
After looking over one of the controller files, I found the error and now the routes work as expected. However, I still feel that my routes look clunky, and since there will be more models, boats, tractors, etc, I dont think the way the routes are written now will hold up.

Comment: what is the problem, or error?

Comment: Assuming you're on Rails 4, you can visit `localhost:3000/rails/info/routes` and see how these get translated into actual paths. Or from the command line: `rake routes`.

Comment: Use `rake routes` and tell what you've got and what you expected and maybe someone can help.

Comment: I guess I was thinking there was something with my syntax. I am self taught and very few people have seen my code. But since everybody is suggesting to use rake routes - which I can't see how to do a rails app with out it, probably means I need to have an even better understanding of routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it is because you are using `resources :trucks`, when you use the `resouces` it calls the CRUD methods. if you want certain routes you need to specify them, for example: `resources :trucks, only: [:create, :destroy]`

Comment: This might be where I am confused, on the trucks model, I need all the CRUD methods, so if I say something like, only: [:create, :destroy] would I still be able to use the truck show or edit?

Comment: no, you would need to specify so it would be :trucks, only: [:create, :destroy, :show, :edit] is there any other page that you are trying to access?